# Automatically position TikZ arrows so their heads don't overlap at node

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider this MWE:

[image]

Is there a way to automatically position these arrows so that their heads do not overlap at node `A`? I want the two arrowheads to be separated.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=0.3mm]
\tikzset{nodestyle/.style={circle,inner sep=1pt,align=center,draw=black}}
\node [nodestyle] at (1,1) (A) {A};
\node [nodestyle] at (2,3) (B) {B};
\node [nodestyle] at (3,4) (C) {C};
\draw [<->] (A)--(B);
\draw [<->] (A)--(C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I know there is a way to manually adjust the arrows. For example, if I use `(A.north)--(B)` and `(A.north east)--(C)` the arrow heads do not overlap. However, I'm interested in a solution that doesn't require manual adjustment. Can TikZ 'calculate' the arrowheads are going to overlap and re-position them?

Using

```
\draw [<->] (A.north)--(B);
\draw [<->] (A.north east)--(C);
```

[image]

Comment: What you would achieve? i.e. Do you want the heads at a greater distance or that have a common head?

Comment: I want the heads to be separate. But I'm interested in an automatic solution that doesn't require manual adjusting. If such a thing is possible.

Comment: I guess you are aware of the fact that if a solution exists, it will require you to specify all arrows at once. Otherwise Ti*k*Z would have to remember that it already drew an arrow in the same region, which it doesn't. Or, at least, you'd have to remember the arrow yourself. A lot of effort compared to the manual adjustment.

Comment: @marmot Instead of using north, south, east, west etc. Is there a way to specify the direction using an angle instead?

Comment: @Milo Yes, of course. E.g. `A.45` . Just do `\draw [<->] (A.70)--(B);
\draw [<->] (A.30)--(C);` in your code.